# Microsoft REST-ler fuzzer - unable to use Proxy and Authentication token when doing fuzzy testing

Tags: fuzzer, fuzz-testing

Trying to fuzz test my node.js project with Microsoft's REST-ler fuzzer by pointing to a swagger json.
I am trying to use https://github.com/microsoft/restler-fuzzer and running into issues with proxy. Getting outside our proxy allows me to start the test but I am unable to use our Authentication token as defined here https://github.com/microsoft/restler-fuzzer/blob/main/docs/user-guide/SettingsFile.md. I tried using the location and pointed to a file authentication_token.txt with just the JWT token inside it as follows:

```
{
    "authentication": {
        "token": {
          "location": "..../restler-fuzzer/authentication_token.txt",
          "token_refresh_interval":  300
        }
    }
}
```

I pointed to this in the command line run:

python3 -B ".../restler-fuzzer/restler_bin/restler/../engine/restler.py" --restler_grammar "../restler-fuzzer/restler_working_dir/Compile/grammar.py" --custom_mutations "../restler-fuzzer/restler_working_dir/Compile/dict.json" --set_version 9.1.1    --no_ssl   --settings "../restler-fuzzer/restler_user_settings.json"     --include_user_agent --no_tokens_in_logs t --garbage_collection_interval 30 --fuzzing_mode directed-smoke-test

```
No success.
Then I tried changing the engine_settings.json to add the authentication.token.location there.Ran it as follows:
```

python3 -B "../restler-fuzzer/restler_bin/restler/../engine/restler.py" --restler_grammar "../restler-fuzzer/restler_working_dir/Compile/grammar.py" --custom_mutations "../restler-fuzzer/restler_working_dir/Compile/dict.json" --set_version 9.1.1    --no_ssl   --settings "../restler-fuzzer/restler_working_dir/Compile/engine_settings.json"     --include_user_agent --no_tokens_in_logs t --garbage_collection_interval 30 --fuzzing_mode fuzz

```
Actual directory path was marked as ../. None worked. 
I get an error:
```

Authentication failed when refreshing token:

Using Token authentication method:
TokenAuthMethod.LOCATION
with error invalid imaginary literal (, line 1)

TIA,

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I solved it, changing the relative path for absolute path according to this: https://github.com/microsoft/restler-fuzzer/issues/460